# How to combine every line with it's subsequent line in a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file **z.txt**. It looks like this:

```
alcoholic
alert
algebra
alibi
blablabla
...
```

How can I use python to make each line look like this (**combined with it's subsequent line**):

```
alcoholic alert
alert algebra
algebra alibi
alibi blablabla
blablabla ...
```

The incomplete code I have looks like this:

```
with open('z.txt','r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        line =
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to construct a list containing the lines of the desired output. Finally, I'll write those lines to a file named `z_out.txt`.

Let suppose your `z.txt` has the following contents in it.

> z.txt

```
alcoholic
alert
algebra
alibi
blablabla
```

Now, you can try like this.

> construct.py

```
output_lines = []

with open("z.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    l =  len(lines)

    if l <= 1:
        if l == 1:
            output_lines = lines[0]
    else:
        # strip() is to remove `\n` from end of `lines[index]`
        output_lines = [lines[index].strip() + ' ' + lines[index + 1] for index in range(l-1)]

print(output_lines)
# ['alcoholic alert\n', 'alert algebra\n', 'algebra alibi\n', 'alibi blablabla']

# If you wish to save it in a file named `z_out.txt`
with open("z_out.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(output_lines)
```

> z_out.txt

```
alcoholic alert
alert algebra
algebra alibi
alibi blablabla
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility using list comprehension, giving you the output in the form of a list.

```
with open('z.txt','r') as f: 
    wordlist = f.read().split('\n')

>>>wordlist
['alcoholic', 'alert', 'algebra', 'alibi', 'blablabla']

combineduo = [' '.join([x.strip(), y.strip()]) for x,y in zip(wordlist[:-1],wordlist[1:])]

>>>combineduo
['alcoholic alert', 'alert algebra', 'algebra alibi', 'alibi blablabla']
```